# How to get a clean 50 kHz square-wave with 555 timer (Astable Mode)?

Tags: 555

I can't get a pure square wave above a few kilohertz. Everything is fine at the lower frequencies, but I would like a clock speed of between 50 and 100 kilohertz. Unfortunately, there is a distortion on the rising edge. Is it possible? Is that the nature of this chip?
Here is 28kHz waveform example.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try dampening the drive strength. Also use a good ground clip to your oscilloscope probe. Not a long lead with alligator clip.

Comment: Also, there is some kind of load when you're measuring this circuit?

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 Thanks. Signal 555 controls an ADC - TLC0820 WR / RDY pin directly.

Comment: Might try adding a small resistor on the line 1-15 Ohms.

Comment: Have you got bypass caps on the 555?

Comment: @Justme Yes, 10nF at pin 5, 470nF at VCC to ground. Reset pin is VCC.

Comment: Are you using the oscilloscope in AC setting? Why? Are those 10x probes or selectable and set to 10x? What probes they are (make/model)? Is the probe compensation properly adjusted? Are you using the spring ground pin instead of alligator clip wire? Is the scope bandwidth enough to measure the fast edges? Oscilloscope make/model?

Comment: @Justme It's an R&S HMO1002 scope. The probe is set to 10x, they are BK PR150B. Well compensated. No, I use alligator clip.. unfortunately(?) This is set to full bandwidth 20Mhz.

Comment: *Is that the nature of this chip?* No but the waveform will heavily depend on **how you do the measurement**. Know that a squarewave contains many harmonic frequencies which can trigger high frequency resonances in your measurement setup. Do you use wires? Sure you do. 1mm of wire has 1nH of inductance. Wires also have capacitance to other wires and conductive surfaces. There are plenty of opportunities for resonances that will be visible in your measurement. Make sure all connections are **as short as posible**, use a 10:1 probe, calibrate the probe. Measure again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual reason for ringing is wire inductance including ground clip resonating with the probe cable capacitance.  With you short all the leads incl. gnd clip to 1cm that inductance of ~<10nH/cm will make it better. To improve further requires a load resistor, either pullup to Vcc or down or both.

Comment: @Tonny Stewart Thanks a lot. 1k pullup resistor helped. It's perfect right now.